# How to filter an exact match of ForeignKey field when using Django Elasticsearch

Tags: django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm using [Django Elasticsearch DSL](https://django-elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with Django 3 app, PostgreSQL and Elasticsearch. As models I have (simplified version)

```
class Jornal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length = 250,blank=True,null = True,unique = True)

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    description = models.TextField()
    jornal = models.ForeignKey(Jornal,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name = 'jornal')
```

I want to filter a query by the jornal slug. For that, I have this

```
q = Q("multi_match", query=termo, fields=['title','description'])
entries = ArticleDocument.search().query(q)
entries = entries.filter("match",jornal__slug = jornal_slug)
```

It works except for the jornal slug. It does not filter as an exact match.

Comment: Seems the same question as the following: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/issues/1339

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related with how the `slug` field of `jornal` model was indexed.

I initially indexed it with:

```
'slug': fields.TextField()
```

But being a slug, it has several values with hyfen, and at the time of indexing, elasticsearch breaks it into multiple tokens. To avoid this I had to defined it as a `keyword` field:

```
'slug': fields.KeywordField()
```